# avoid auto-refresh on clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple HTML code

```
<form class="searchbox" action="" >
<input type="search" placeholder="Search KB" id="SearchField"/>
<button value="search" id="SearchButton">&nbsp;</button>
</form>
```

and simple event listener

```
$('#SearchButton').on("click",function(events) {
// your stuff
alert("work darn it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
events.preventDefault();
var bla = $('#SearchField').val();
console.log("bla")
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(bla);
  return false;
  });
```

when i click button page keeps refreshing
when i put this
    
It doenst run my event listener when i do this

I am not getting where i am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Jquery like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#SearchButton').click(function() {
    alert('working fine..');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: i am not getting how s this return false different from one in my sample. can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Update like below,

```
$(function(){
$('#SearchButton').click(function() {
    alert('working fine..');
    var bla = $('#SearchField').val();
    alert('Search field name :'+bla);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work now. You've to just disable the default function that submit button in a form has that is to self post.

```
 $('#SearchButton').on("click",function(e) {
 // Stop propagation & prevent Default action
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault():
alert("work darn it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
var bla = $('#SearchField').val();
console.log("bla")
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(bla);
  return false;
  });
```